# Terminal de Laragon no reconoce el comando de composer dumpautolop, ni composer

Tags: terminal, composer, laragon

estoy aprendido a como usar laravel y parte del curso en el que estoy esta editar composer.json, al momento de introducir el comando de **composer dumpautolop** para que se actualice la parte el documento de json, me dice la terminal " 'composer' no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable." [image: terminal laragon con uso de comando composer dumpautolop y composer update]

Answer (score 0):

El comando que estas buscando es `composer dump-autoload` y posiblemente no te reconozca el comando composer porque hace falta agregarlo a las variables de entorno.
Puedes leer [esto](https://www.srcodigofuente.es/aprender-php/como-instalar-usar-composer-windows-facil) para que te auxilie un poco en agregarlos.